# how to populate date from webservice to xamarin android

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I can't populate date from webservice to xamarin android

```
namespace Printopack
{
  [Activity(Label = "Mainlistview", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
  public class Mainlistview : Activity
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Mainlistview);

        ListView ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        Selling.WebServiceDB ws = new Selling.WebServiceDB();
        ws.OrderStatusListCompleted += Ws_OrderStatusListCompleted;
        ws.OrderStatusListAsync(Convert.ToString(1));
    }

    private void Ws_OrderStatusListCompleted(object sender, Selling.OrderStatusListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        string msg = "";

        if (e.Result.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            msg = e.Result.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // full class
            List<TableItem> tableItems = new List<TableItem>();
            tableItems.Add(new TableItem("" + e.Result, "" + e.Result, Resource.Drawable.Icon));

            ListView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);
        }
    }

    // adpater manage
    public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem>
    {
        List<TableItem> items;
        Activity context;
        public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override TableItem this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Ticket_News, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Heading;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.SubHeading;
            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);
            return view;
        }
    }

    public class TableItem
    {
        public string Heading;
        public string SubHeading;
        public int ImageResourceId;
        public TableItem(string Heading, string SubHeading, int ImageResourceId)
        {
            this.Heading = Heading;
            this.SubHeading = SubHeading;
            this.ImageResourceId = ImageResourceId;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in this line:

`tableItems.Add(new TableItem("" + e.Result, "" + e.Result, Resource.Drawable.Icon));`

You're adding the `e.Result` as one item and I think the `Result` holds the complete list. You should loop through the entries in the `e.Result` and call `tableItems.Add` for each of them.

Similar to this:

```
foreach (var item in e.Result)
{
    tableItems.Add(new TableItem("" + item.Property, "" + item.Property1, Resource.Drawable.Icon));
}
```